# Jenkins (not admin) Users Password reset/Username change

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I just added the Security to Jenkins.

Jenkins’ own user database enabled
Matrix based security configured
Now i'm configuring and installing the Role matrix plugin.

In case someone want to change his password he just have to login, click on this user configuration and change his password, what if they forgot their password or if I want to change their username?

- **What is the standard procedure to follow bt the administrator in order to reset change his password, or at least delete and recreate the user?**
- **What if the admin want to change a username? is there any standard way to do it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are the admin you can change password of any user through

> 'People' --> 'Select_any_user_listed' --> 'Configure' --> 'Password'

Just erase the old password and write a new one there.

if you want to delete a user go to:

> 'Manage Jenkins' --> 'Manage Users' --> 'press the red button corresponding to the user'

or go to this url:

```
http://<jenkins.url>/user/<username>/delete
```